# React Native doesn't execute onpress function

Tags: reactjs, react-native

```
        for(var index in preguntas.questions) {
            var attr1 = preguntas.questions[index]
            console.log(sum + " ***********************************************pregunta" + attr1.text )
            for(var index2 in attr1.answers) {
            var attr4 = attr1.answers[index2];
            respuesta.push(
                <View key = {index2} >
                    <RadioButton   onPress={() =>  this.onSubmitPressed(index2)} >
                        <Text>{attr4}</Text>
                    </RadioButton>

                </View >
            )
            }
            questions.push(
                <View key = {index}>
                    <View>
                        <Text >{attr1.text}</Text>

                        {respuesta}
                    </View>
                </View>
            )
            var respuesta = [];
            /*for(var index55 in attr2.answers) {
                var attr4 = attr2.answers[index2];
                console.log(sum + " ***********************************************" + attr4 )
                respuesta.push(`enter code here`
                <View key = {index55}>
                    <View>
                        <Text >{attr4}</Text>
                    </View>
                </View>
                )
            }*/



        }
```

Good morning I'm trying to run the onpres function that is onSubmitPressed but it will not let me and I get the following error
 ReactNativeJS: NETWORK error: TypeError: undefined is not a function (evaluating 'this.onSubmitPressed (index2)')

The code is inside the renderMovie function
If I could help with that greetings

Comment: Can you show the whole code? Where did you place that function? Is it in the same file as the code above? And is this a reactjs (web) or react-native (mobile apps) question?

Answer (score 1):

So it looks like the onSubmitPressed is not defined, what you will need to do is declare that function in your component and then also bind(this) if you want to use the state and any other values inside your this.

```
onSubmitPressed(index2) {
  //Do whatever you would like on your submit
}

constructor(props) {
  super(props)
  this.state = {};
  this.onSubmitPressed = this.onSubmitPressed.bind(this);
}
```